# MongoDB - average of a feature after slicing the max of another feature in a group of documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, grouping

I am very new in mongodb and trying to work around a couple of queries, which I am not even sure if they 're feasible.

The structure of each document is:

```
{
     "_id"  : {
              "$oid": Text
              },
     "grade": Text,
     "type" : Text,
     "score": Integer,
     "info" : {
              "range"  : NumericText,
              "genre"  : Text,
              "special": {keys:values}
              }
};
```

The first query would give me:

- per grade (thinking I have to group by "grade")
- the highest range (thinking I have to call $max:$range, it should work with a string)
- the score average (thinking I have to call $avg:$score)

I tried something like the following, which apparently is wrong:

```
collection.aggregate([{
                       '$group': {'_id':'$grade',
                                  'highest_range': {'$max':'$info',
                                  'average_score': {'$avg':'$score'}}}
                       }])
```

The second query would give the distinct `genre` records.

Any help is valuable!

---

ADDITION - providing an example of the document and the output:

```
{
     "_id"  : {
              "$oid": '60491ea71f8'
              },
     "grade": D,
     "type" : Shop,
     "score": 4,
     "info" : {
              "range"  : "2",
              "genre"  : 'Pet shop',
              "special": {'ClientsParking':True,
                          'AcceptsCreditCard':True,
                          'BikeParking':False}
                         }
};
```

And the output I am looking into is something within lines:

```
[{grade: A, "highest_range":"4", "average_score":3.5},
 {grade: B, "highest_range":"7", "average_score":8.3},
 {grade: C, "highest_range":"3", "average_score":2.4}]
```

Comment: Can you give some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: I couldn't understand. Do you want to get `highest_range` through all documents? Or for per document? And you're thinking of averaging as well. Then these fields will be the same in all documents? Can you add some sample documents and an expecting result to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      '$group': {
         '_id': '$grade',
         'highest_range': { '$max': '$info.range' },
         'average_score': { '$avg': '$score' }
      }
   }
])
```

However, `$min`, `$max`, `$avg` works only on numbers, not strings.
You could try `{ '$first': '$info.range' }` or `{ '$last': '$info.range' }`. But it requires `$sort` for proper result. Not clear what you mean by "highest range".